# How can I get wordpress slug without certain phrase?

Tags: slug

I got this code: `<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>` and I get slug of current post page example: "dog-training"

And my wordpress posts are like this:

domain.com/dog-training/
domain.com/dog-toys/
domain.com/dog-food/
etc.

And I need to get the slug but only the part "toys", "food" and "training" so I need to get rid of the "dog-" part.

Will You help me with this. I`m not a programmer ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605060/how-do-i-replace-part-of-a-string-in-php).

You'll want to use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$permalink = get_the_permalink(); 
$permalink = str_replace("dog-", "", $permalink);
```